# Wrapping data file to golang app and use in exec

Tags: linux, go

I would like to wrap a data file (~1MB) to golang app and then use that data in `os.exec`. The app runs on Linux.

How to define the data in the app, as a `string` or `[]byte`, variable, or Const?

Should be defined in a global scope, or wrapped in a `func`?

How to pass the data from the app memory to the **executed** process ?

Answer (score 0):

For building the data file(s) in to your program, you have a number of choices. You are correct in that you could manually copy/paste the data file(s) in to the program as types `string`, `[]byte` as variables, but there are other packages/applications for go that handle this for you already that can also minimize your app's memory footprint. One example that comes to mind is `go-bindata` ([link to repo](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata)) which does just this.

As for using the file in `os/exec`, I'm assuming you're trying to either pass the entire file to the program using either a file path or a raw string. For file paths, you would have to write the entire file to disk first. If you're trying to pass the entire file contents as a raw string, you can still use `go-bindata` or a `string` of the data file as `arg` in `os/exec.Command`.

P.S. - `go-bindata` has not seen updates in a while, so I would encourage you to seek more active forks or alternatives if you're having trouble using it.